# Can't boot ubuntu installer

Tags: 13.10, preinstallation

I have an old Elo Entuitive touch computer with Windows XP and I wanted to install Ubuntu with an usb stick, but I couldn't boot it with 13.10 at all. So I went with 13.04 and the same error. Whenever it boots, it just shows that Ubuntu is loading and then it just reboots itself.

The Elo specs are 512MB of RAM and 320GB of disk, so it passes the minimum requirements. I didn't try with other distros, but I don't think It's something Ubuntu specific.

What could it be the cause of this? Should I check something on the BIOS?

UPDATE:

To give more information, whenever I boot the usb stick it only gets as far as this screen:

[image]

UPDATE 2:

I just found out the error was because the Elo touchscreens aren't supported by the X.org version Ubuntu ships. I was able to install Ubuntu with alternate but now I can't start the graphic server.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you  have not made you usb stick bootable correctly.
Try to make it bootable again.

If you are using windows , I would recommend to use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3) to make it bootable.

Comment: Just tried the usb stick on my computer and it boots fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try flashing your BIOS to the most recent version, if one is available. Also try using an alternate USB stick. There have been times where flashing the BIOS has resolved USB bootable media issues, but there have also been times where, no matter which computer i'm trying to install to, the USB just will not boot correctly, but works fine as storage.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this pc has VIA Eden 1Ghz processor.

http://www.allthingspos.com/elo/1529l-touchcomputer.htm

I vote for CPU incompatibility. Boot any 32bit version of Ubuntu, and try custom boot loader options. See instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

You definitely need to delete "quiet" option from boot loader [command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD_Boot_Option_Configuration_Line) - then you'll see actual error instead of loading progress.

Comment: The problem is I can't go further than [this screen.](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/_media/installation/live_cd_maverick1.png)

Comment: Use your keyboard --> <-- buttons to select other options. If keyboard is not recognized, check BIOS options.

Comment: No response either. Just tried with other OSes and it didn't boot as well, so it might be a problem with the computer because I did try with both GRUB and syslinux.